# Tratar todas as cores hexadecimais em um arquivo.css usando php e regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

não sei se podem me ajudar mas quero substituir a cor no formato "#xxxxxx" em um CSS através de Expressão regular e PHP.

eu tenho uma função que calcula a cor e substitui pela cor inversa.
Preciso pegar o CSS e inverter todas as cores no formato "#xxxxxx" pela sua cor negativa.
não sei qual a melhor forma de fazer isto.

eu tenho a função que inverte as cores pronta.

```
    FUNCTION inverseHex( $color )
$color       = TRIM($color);
         $prependHash = FALSE;

         IF(STRPOS($color,'#')!==FALSE) {
              $prependHash = TRUE;
              $color       = STR_REPLACE('#',NULL,$color);
         }

         SWITCH($len=STRLEN($color)) {
              CASE 3:
                   $color=PREG_REPLACE("/(.)(.)(.)/","\\1\\1\\2\\2\\3\\3",$color);
              CASE 6:
                   BREAK;
              DEFAULT:
                   TRIGGER_ERROR("Invalid hex length ($len). Must be (3) or (6)", E_USER_ERROR);
         }

         IF(!PREG_MATCH('/[a-f0-9]{6}/i',$color)) {
              $color = HTMLENTITIES($color);
              TRIGGER_ERROR( "Invalid hex string #$color", E_USER_ERROR );
         }

         $r = DECHEX(255-HEXDEC(SUBSTR($color,0,2)));
         $r = (STRLEN($r)>1)?$r:'0'.$r;
         $g = DECHEX(255-HEXDEC(SUBSTR($color,2,2)));
         $g = (STRLEN($g)>1)?$g:'0'.$g;
         $b = DECHEX(255-HEXDEC(SUBSTR($color,4,2)));
         $b = (STRLEN($b)>1)?$b:'0'.$b;

         RETURN ($prependHash?'#':NULL).$r.$g.$b;
```

e tenho as expressões regulares para localizar as cores:

```
 #\b\w{5}+[d]\b
```

Porém não sei como usar o **preg_replace** para percorrer o texto e substituir cada ocorrência, não por uma outra array mas passando a função inverseHex() acima, e fazer isso em todo o CSS. para imprimir o CSS com todas as cores negativas

se alguém me der uma dica, eu já consigo me virar pra produzir o código.
 tenho que fazer isso em 30 arquivos CSS com milhares de linhas cada.

Comment: numa nota à parte, é possível inverter as cores em CSS com a propriedade `filter: invert(100%);`

Comment: Obrigado amigo, realmente isto atende, mas teria problema na manutenção pois teria que por sempre as cores negativas de novas propriedades. por isso parti pra uma ação mais radical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estou inserindo o código completo da solução para o problema que tive, caso ajude outras pessoas.

```
<?php

//Função em PHP que irá alterar a cor para sua forma negativa
//Gerando uma saída com o arquivo CSS prontinho pra ser salvo.

FUNCTION inverseHex( $color )
{


     $color       = TRIM($color);
     $prependHash = FALSE;

     IF(STRPOS($color,'#')!==FALSE) {
          $prependHash = TRUE;
          $color       = STR_REPLACE('#',NULL,$color);
     }

     SWITCH($len=STRLEN($color)) {
          CASE 3:
               $color=PREG_REPLACE("/(.)(.)(.)/","\\1\\1\\2\\2\\3\\3",$color);
          CASE 6:
               BREAK;
          DEFAULT:
               TRIGGER_ERROR("Invalid hex length ($len). Must be (3) or (6)", E_USER_ERROR);
     }

     IF(!PREG_MATCH('/[a-f0-9]{6}/i',$color)) {
          $color = HTMLENTITIES($color);
          TRIGGER_ERROR( "Invalid hex string #$color", E_USER_ERROR );
     }

     $r = DECHEX(255-HEXDEC(SUBSTR($color,0,2)));
     $r = (STRLEN($r)>1)?$r:'0'.$r;
     $g = DECHEX(255-HEXDEC(SUBSTR($color,2,2)));
     $g = (STRLEN($g)>1)?$g:'0'.$g;
     $b = DECHEX(255-HEXDEC(SUBSTR($color,4,2)));
     $b = (STRLEN($b)>1)?$b:'0'.$b;

     RETURN ($prependHash?'#':NULL).$r.$g.$b;

}

$str = $textoDoArquivoCSS//arquivo de texto, no caso eu fiz por Curl.

function inverseHexRegex($elements) {

   return inverseHex($elements[1]);
}
$str = preg_replace_callback('/(#[a-f0-9]{3,6})/i', 'inverseHexRegex', $str);

echo $str;

?>
```

com essa saída, eu só salvo o arquivo e já está pronta a versão negativa dele.
OBS: este código NÃo vai tratar cores expressadas em palavras: black, red, etc... nem cores em RBG: rgb(xxx,xxx,xxx).

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver o problema com a função **[preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace-callback.php)**, foi só inserir a minha função de CORES em *create_function()* para **callback**. Obrigado a todos.